# Phonegap or Xamarin: Which is better for cross platform?

Tags: xamarin, hybrid-mobile-app

While most articles and posts I have been through discuss about *Native vs Xamarin* or *Native vs Hybrid(Phonegap)* I searched around and very few with Xamarin and Phonegap.

Me and a group of my friends are developing **a photo-sharing app** of sorts and **we want it to be cross platform**. But we're stuck with the dilemma of going with Phonegap or Xamarin.
While price-wise both are free(except for iOS development) and we're familiar with the languages and technologies used by both, we're at a stalemate arguing on points such as;

1. Developer support
2. API availability
3. Ability to debug and update easily.

Whichever platform which delivers the best of all of this is what we hope to go with.

Comment: unless you have some clear statistics to backup your premise, this is just calling for opinions and arguments

Comment: @Jason I edited the question to steer away from an argument, what we're looking for is a clear reason to opt for one platform instead of the other

Comment: There are too many variables that go into questions like this. It's really up to you and your group of friends to make decisions on your situation. All of these points can be figured out with a couple days of using each framework.